# Change base python counts in

Tags: python, comparison

sorry for the stupid question, i need to change base of python counts in.

To compare numbers of values from 1 to 7 with first 7 alphabetical letters (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

I know that it is possible to compare them using <,>,== operators,

But i need the in a row ones, my order looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

So for the input:

```
1,1,2,5,7,A,B,C,E,G
```

I expect the output to be as the following:

```
7,A,B,C
```

I need to the items that are only in a row of more than 3 (converting letters in numbers and substituting won't help, since the code will be too complicated).

Is there any option to create a table of comparison (separate function or something) or change the base python counts in, not decimal but the other one.

I was trying to look for that information, but nothing found. Please advice.

Comment: ``` table of comparison ``` - maybe like a dictionary with letters for keys and numbers for values?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but converting letters to numbers is not that dificult: `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G']; t = {l[i]:i for i in range(len(l))}` Then use `t[something]` to get the number corresponding to each simbol.

Comment: What if there IS more than one sequence of three or more - like ``` 1,2,3,4,7,6,5,A,B,C,T,U,W,X,Y,Z```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about make a dictionary that map digits to numbers:

```
digits = '1234567ABCDEFG'
digit_map = {d:i for i, d in enumerate(digits)}

prev = 9999
matches = []
for n in '11257ABCEG':
    if digit_map[n] == prev + 1:
        matches.append(n)
    else:
        if len(matches) >= 3:
            print(matches)
        matches = [n]
    prev = digit_map[n]
```

output:

```
['7', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: and with list as an input? ^^

Comment: @MotherLand, Just replace `'11257ABCEG'` with the list `['1', '1', '2', '5', '7', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G']`.

Comment: @MotherLand, Iterating over string yields characters (1-char strings)